# camera position / rotation wrong when not (0,0,0) pointer lock controls

Tags: three.js

when ever I set camera.position anything other than (0,0,0) my rotation with pointer lock controls is all over the place. The whole scene goes crazy.

It seems to work if I change the position of yawObject and not camera.
So I guess that is ok,

How can i change the default rotation of pointer lock controls - I want to start by looking to the right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
controls.getObject().position.set( x, y, z);
```